# How to move photo to public folder with react after upload the photo using upload input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm working on a dashboard project with the CRUD system on a JSON placeholder fake API server, while the user creates a product with a photo I need to move any selected photo after uploading it to the public folder then using upload input and then export its path to JSON file API.

```
function Product() {
  const [path, setPath] = useState('');
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    id: nanoid(),
    title: '',
    price: '',
    description: '',
    category: '',
    image: path,
    rating: {
      rate: 0,
      count: 0,
    },
  });

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { value, name, files } = e.target;
    setFormData(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
    setPath(URL.createObjectURL(files[0]));
  };
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75389975/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You can't do that without a server